# Upgrading to Django 1.7 from 1.5 missing textile

Tags: python, django

Textile has been deprecated in django, I have't found any docs on a replacement for this, what's the alternative now for django?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

textile `import textile` is now part of python and the reason django removed it so I've made a template filter that will use it.

Comment: textile **is not** a part of Python. You need to install a package like [python-textile](https://github.com/textile/python-textile). I guess you don't get an import error because the old Django template tag required it, so you have already installed it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [django-markup-deprecated](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-markup-deprecated) package with the code from the old `django.contrib.markup` package which was removed.